# How to get credentials for multiple scopes from identity server 3?

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver3

I'm trying to get credentials from Identity Server 3 using the `IdentityModel.TokenClient`. Getting credentials for one role works fine, but I need to get the credentials for two scopes in one request. The scopes are "api" and "myrole".

As far as I know getting multiple roles should be done by simply separating them with a space, like so:

```
var client = new TokenClient(
    "https://theidentityserver.com/connect/token",
    "myclient",
    "mysecret");

var result = await client.RequestClientCredentialsAsync("api myrole");
```

This generates a request:

```
> POST https://theidentityserver.com/connect/token HTTP/1.1 Connection:
> Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Accept:
> application/json Authorization: Basic [auth token here]
> Content-Length: 46 Host: theidentityserver.com
> 
> grant_type=client_credentials&scope=api+myrole
```

And yields a response:

> {"error":"invalid_scope"}

As you can see, the `TokenClient` generates a request where the scopes are separated by a plus sign and not by a space. Is there any way around this or am I doing something very wrong?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to IdentityServer4?

Comment: Also, have you seen this? https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/3232

Comment: @Dai unfortunately the server is not in our control. Thank you for the github link. It may be that the server side is not configured properly?

Comment: Invalid_scope means that the client is not allowed to request this scope. Check the client configuration on the server